# Can a <name> tag have a @nullValue and still have text inside?

Tags: hl7, cda

The current implementation of a CCDA generator I'm working on, prints a message on a [`<name>` tag](http://www.cdapro.com/know/25041) (in header sections, where no `<text>` is available) when something's name is not found:

```
<name>No information</name>
```

I know the right way to express not found information is through the @nullFlavor attribute:

```
<name nullFlavor="NI" />
```

But right now there is a component on the application that reads the value on the tag and shows it in a human-readable view of the CCDA document. If I use @nullflavor only, the field that shows such name will be empty, instead of "No information".

In order to avoid changing such component, I was thinking on adding the @nullFlavor attribute *but* still letting the message there:

```
<name nullFlavor="NI">No information</name>
```

I know this is syntactically correct, because I've tested it with the [reference validator](https://ttpedge.sitenv.org/ttp/#/validators) and it passes. My question is: **from a semantic point of view, is it valid?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's valid. The particular specification in question - the v3 abstract data types, simple says:

```
invariant(ST x) where x.nonNull {
   x.headCharacter.notEmpty;
};
```

So if there's no nullFlavor, there must be some content. But the reverse rule is not applied; there can be content if there's a nullFlavor

Comment: I found the [datatype specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ubl/lcsc/doc/qateam/Comment%20work%20from%20HL7/datatypes.html) and it says `invariant(ANY x) {x.nonNull.equals(x.nullFlavor.isNull);}`. Considering the `equals` works as "if and only if" and the definitions of `isNull` and `nonNull`, it is right to imply that (in a semantic sense) if `x` has a non null `nullFlavor`, then `x` is considered null, _regardless of the components/other properties of `x`_?

Comment: Yes, It is considered null regardless of the other components. Note, then, that the implication is that null here is not the same as a null pointer in a 3gl

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not restricted, my point of view is that it is not a good strategy. I understand that you have a restriction regarding this component but, when you are building a CDA, it is important to keep in mind that it is something to be shared with everyone, and I would never expect to find content inside a `nullFlavor` attributed element.